# How to improve accuracy of Named entity recognition (NER) tagger on local data?

Tags: nlp, named-entity-recognition

I am using NER from spacy. Its giving incorrect results for few words. Its trained on general dataset. How can I customize on my local data.

For example,

```
Person -  {'Mike Miller', 'Miller', 'Infantino', 'Gianni Infantino'}
Location -  {'England', 'UK', 'Europe', 'Telegraph'}
```

Here, "Telegraph" is incorrectly is assigned to location.

Answer (score 1):

@Ravikm, excellent question. In Spacy, you can assign a word manually. For example, "Tesla" to ORG. Source: screenshot from Jose Portilla's NLP course on Udemy.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unless you retrain the model that is used to generate the NER results, you cannot make it better.

However, what you could do is, if spacy provides probabilites for each of the tag, you could do some statistical modeling on top of it, however I would keep this as a secondary option.

Comment: I beg to differ regarding re-training your model. You can manually add / change words in Spacy. See my answer below.

Comment: @FrancoSwiss - Even if you could add this manually, you still have to retrain the model for the next predictions to get better right? If not, then its a cool feature that I was not aware off.

Comment: indeed it's a cool feature. No, no need to retrain as the model knows that Tesla is an ORG.